# populate ObservableCollection<string> using string array

Tags: c#, observablecollection

All,

Need some help here..
I have an array of string and need to bind that to ObservableCollection

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Amit, when you say "bind", is this a one-time thing, or do you need to update the ObservableCollection when the array changes?

Comment: @GaryJohnson - Thanks for quick response, its one time activity.

Comment: @GaryJohnson, Thanks, it worked... in case lets say, if it changes in future (Not a one time activity)... then what are the options to reflect the values in the collection, Thanks once again in advance.

Comment: Oscar's answer is good. If the string array changes, there are many ways to deal with that, all depending on your implementation and needs. If you need to know when the array changes, you may want to consider making it an ObservableCollection in the first place, or poll it on some sort of refresh event, or if you own the code updating the array, use an event or something to signal that the ObservableCollection needs to be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class can receive an `IEnumerable<T>` on the constructor. You can use it like this:

```
string[] items = ...
ObservableCollection<string> observableItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(items);
```

**Edit:** If your array changes in the future, your `ObsevableCollection` won't. If you want that, please, specify it in your question.